# list onclick event problem in php

Tags: php, list, onclick

I'm trying to display the new dynamic list by clicking dynamic list. Why do i call them dynamic list? Because the data is from database.

My **idea** is generating a list of companies, when i click one company, a list of all sites in the company is displayed; And then when i click the one site of one company, a list of all employees in the site is displayed.

Now i have met a problem. When i click any item in list of companies, a list of sites in the last item of company list shows. And when i click any item in the list of sites, a list of employees of last item in sites is showed.

Do you know why?

Here is the code and result image:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(id,id2,id3) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == 'block') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                if (id2 != undefined)document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
                if (id3 != undefined)document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#main{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#hidden {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    left:280px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: none;
}
#hidden2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-12px;
    left:580px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: none;
}
#hidden3 {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightpink;
    display: none;
}
</style>
    <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        include("./conn/connect.php");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM entreprise ORDER BY id";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("result failed: ".mysql_error());
    ?>
<div id="main" >
    <?php
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden','hidden2','hidden3');\">".$row['name'].'<li>';
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE eid = '".$row['id']."'";
            //$query2 = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE eid = ".$row['id'];
            //$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("query2 result error".mysql_error());
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("query2 result error".mysql_error());
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    ?>
</div>
<div id="hidden" >
    <?php
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
            echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden2','hidden3')\">".$row2['name'].'< >';
            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM salarie WHERE siteid =".$row2['id'];
            //echo $query3;
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die("query3 result error".mysql_error());
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    ?>
</div>
<div id="hidden2" >
    <?php
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){
            echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden3')\">".$row3['prenom'].'< >';
            $query4 = "SELECT * FROM salarie WHERE id =".$row3['id'];
            $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die("query4 result error".mysql_error());
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    ?>
</div>
<div id="hidden3">
    <?php
        echo "<table>";
        while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4)){
            echo "<tr><td>".$row4['prenom'].'</td>';
            echo "<td>".$row4['nom'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Result image:

[image]

Comment: wow... should use a framework, templating system, or at least split into MVC.

Comment: i have ever heard of jquery and ajax. But can someone guide me how to do this with ajax or jquery? Thanks so much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple: Your PHP code is executed **ONCE** when you access the site.

So for example the result of this block

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden','hidden2','hidden3');\">".$row['name'].'<li>';
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE eid = '".$row['id']."'";
        //$query2 = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE eid = ".$row['id'];
        //$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("query2 result error".mysql_error());
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("query2 result error".mysql_error());
}
```

is that `$result2` holds all the sites of the last company in your list. This is then used in the next loop to generate the corresponding list of sites. Look at the source  of the generated HTML file.

PHP is a server side language, the code is executed at the server and it is not re-executed by your Javascript functions (i.e. not executed in the browser).

What you are after is dynamically loading the data from your server with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and pass into the generated HTML.

**Edit:**

You could also do it without Ajax: Rewrite your PHP like this:

```
$sitequeries = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<li onclick=\"showSites('sites_$row['id']');\">".$row['name'].'<li>';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE eid = '".$row['id']."'";
        $sitequeries[$row['id']] = mysql_query($query2 or die("query2 result error".mysql_error());
}
```

and

```
<?php
    foreach($sitequeries as $id => $query) {
        echo "<ul class='sites' id='sites_$id'>";

        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            //...
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

This is not a working example but should give you the right idea. You have to adjust your JS accordingly to show only the corresponding lists, e.g.:

```
function showSites(id) {
   // Hide all lists with class 'site' here and only display the list with id 'id' e.g. 'sites_5'
}
```

But note that this is not a good solution if you have a lot of companies, site, employes, etc. as the generation of the HTML may take a while. Then Ajax is a better choice.

Comment: @Felix, thanks. So you mean, i should accomplish this with AJAX, and it can't finish it with existing code?

Comment: See my edit.. you can do it, I hope it gives you the right idea but if you have a lot of data you should do it with Ajax.

Comment: @Thanks Felix, you have guide me a direction. And it's already half-done. Now with your code, it shows all the sites in all the companies when i click the list of companies. And because i have a lot of companies,sites and employees, the speed is very important. So i have to try to find an Ajax solution.

Comment: jQuery will make your life a lot easier so I recommend reading the tutorial http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: @Felix, Thanks, i'll look at it, try to find how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `toggle()` Function needs **3** Parameters 
You set on some places just 2 parameters

```
echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden2','hidden3')\">".$row2['name'].'< >';
```

Shoud be

```
echo "<li onclick=\"toggle('hidden1','hidden2','hidden3')\">".$row2['name'].'< >';
```

Comment: It's not that problem, i have tested it before. I use toggle() just to control what to display by clicking. But thanks the same.

Comment: Dude, the JS above checks if there is any thid or second parameter. If so, does something with the corresponding DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I would do some things about your code:

1. Split the data acquiring stuff from the rest. At the beginning, get the data from the required tables and keep it in PHP variables. Then, do something with them using a JS framework... something according to your requirements
2. The problem with your approach is that you are NEVER telling anyone which row's ID should be sent... hence, it sends the id from the row selected by default, which happens to be the last one parsed by HTML parser on the browser. It means, the last one...

Comment: @Alfabravo, i was wondering why it always happens. And the last row id makes me confused.  Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code does not match your goal. $result2 will always be the last ID found in $result1, and so on.

If you need to generate result2 based on what the user selects in result1, then you need to either create rows for every possible selection then use javascript to show or hide, or utilize Ajax calls (much better).

Comment: @menkes, thanks, the last ID is always used finally. It makes me frustraing.

Answer (score 0):

Might wanna look into [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead of doing it the way you currently are.  But streetparade is correct.

Comment: @EpicDewd, thanks, do you know any existing jquery plugin for this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to this task is a bit wrong, I think.
What do you do in the first loop? You setting $result2 variable and you want to access it in the next loop. And in next loop $result2 is set to the last record of first loop.
Have you heard about AJAX? jQuery may be?

Comment: @thanks habicht, yes, i think it's a better choice with Ajax or jquery.